# Instruction Level Parallelism (ILP) and out-of-order execution on NVIDIA GPUs

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Do NVIDIA GPUs support out-of-order execution?

My first guess is that they don't contain such expensive hardware. However, when reading the `CUDA progamming guide`, the guide recommends using Instruction Level Parallelism (ILP) to improve performance.

Isn't ILP a feature that hardware supporting out-of-order execution can take advantage from? Or NVIDIA's ILP simply means compiler-level re-ordering of instructions, hence its order is still fixed at runtime. In other words, just the compiler and/or programmer has to arrange the order of instructions in such a way that ILP can be achieved at runtime through in-order executions?

Comment: An out-of-order processor is not required to exploit instruction level parallelism. An in-order processor with superscalar execution can benefit just as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipelining is a common ILP technique and is for sure implemented on NVidia's GPU. I guess you agree that pipelining doesn't rely on out-of-order execution.
Besides, NVidia GPU have multiple warp schedulers from compute capability 2.0 and beyond (2 or 4). If your code has 2 (or more) consecutive and independent instructions in threads (or compiler reorders it that way somehow), you exploit this ILP from scheduler as well.

Here is a well explained question on how 2-wide warp scheduler + pipelining work together. 
[How do nVIDIA CC 2.1 GPU warp schedulers issue 2 instructions at a time for a warp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886002/how-does-the-cuda-warp-scheduler-issue-2-instructions-at-a-time-for-a-warp)

Also checkout Vasily Volkov's presentation on GTC 2010. He experimentally found out how ILP would improve CUDA code performance. http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf

In terms of out-of-order execution on GPU, I don't think so. Hardware instruction reordering, speculative execution all those kind of stuff are too expensive to implement per SM, as you are aware. And thread level parallelism can fill in the gap of lacking out-of-order execution. When true dependency is encountered, some other warps can kick in and fill the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The code below reports an example of Instruction Level Parallelism (ILP).

The `__global__` function in the example simply performs an assignment between two arrays. For the case `ILP=1`, we have as many threads as the number of array elements `N`, so that each thread performs a single assignment. Opposite to that, for the case `ILP=2`, we have a number of `N/2` threads each one processing `2` elements. In general, for the case `ILP=k`, we have a number of `N/k` threads each one processing `k` elements.

Besides the code, below I'm reporting also the timings, performed on an `NVIDIA GT920M` (Kepler architecture), for different values of `N` and `ILP`. As it can be seen:

1. for large values of `N`, a memory bandwidth close to the maximum one for the `GT920M` card, namely, `14.4GB/s`, is reached;
2. for any fixed `N`, changing the value of `ILP` does not change performance.

Concerning point 2., I have also tested the same code on Maxwell, and observed the same behavior (no change in performance against `ILP`). For a change in performance against `ILP`, please see the answer to [The efficiency and performance of ILP for the NVIDIA Kepler architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771730/the-efficiency-and-performance-of-ilp-for-the-nvidia-kepler-architecture) reporting also tests on the Fermi architecture.

The memory speed has been calculated by the following formula:

```
(2.f * 4.f * N * numITER) / (1e9 * timeTotal * 1e-3)
```

where

```
4.f * N * numITER
```

is the number of read OR writes,

```
2.f * 4.f * N * numITER
```

is the number of read AND writes,

```
timeTotal * 1e-3
```

is the time in `seconds` (`timeTotal` is in `ms`).

**THE CODE**

```
// --- GT920m - 14.4 GB/s
//     http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GTX-280M-vs-GeForce-920M

#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE    32

#define DEBUG

/****************************************/
/* INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM KERNEL */
/****************************************/
__global__ void ILPKernel(const int * __restrict__ d_a, int * __restrict__ d_b, const int ILP, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * ILP;

    if (tid >= N) return;

    for (int j = 0; j < ILP; j++) d_b[tid + j * blockDim.x] = d_a[tid + j * blockDim.x];

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    //const int N = 8192;
    const int N = 524288 * 32;
    //const int N = 1048576;
    //const int N = 262144;
    //const int N = 2048;

    const int numITER = 100;

    const int ILP = 16;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    int *h_a = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int *h_b = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        h_a[i] = 2;
        h_b[i] = 1;
    }

    int *d_a; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_a, N * sizeof(int)));
    int *d_b; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_b, N * sizeof(int)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /**************/
    /* ILP KERNEL */
    /**************/
    float timeTotal = 0.f;
    for (int k = 0; k < numITER; k++) {
        timerGPU.StartCounter();
        ILPKernel << <iDivUp(N / ILP, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE >> >(d_a, d_b, ILP, N);
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif
        timeTotal = timeTotal + timerGPU.GetCounter();
    }

    printf("Bandwidth = %f GB / s; Num blocks = %d\n", (2.f * 4.f * N * numITER) / (1e6 * timeTotal), iDivUp(N / ILP, BLOCKSIZE));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_b, d_b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (h_a[i] != h_b[i]) { printf("Error at i = %i for kernel0! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_a[i], h_b[i]); return 1; }

    return 0;

}
```

**PERFORMANCE**

```
GT 920M
N = 512  - ILP = 1  - BLOCKSIZE = 512 (1 block  - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.092 GB / s

N = 1024 - ILP = 1  - BLOCKSIZE = 512 (2 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.15  GB / s

N = 2048 - ILP = 1  - BLOCKSIZE = 512 (4 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.37  GB / s
N = 2048 - ILP = 2  - BLOCKSIZE = 256 (4 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.36  GB / s
N = 2048 - ILP = 4  - BLOCKSIZE = 128 (4 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.35  GB / s
N = 2048 - ILP = 8  - BLOCKSIZE =  64 (4 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.26  GB / s
N = 2048 - ILP = 16 - BLOCKSIZE =  32 (4 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.31  GB / s

N = 4096 - ILP = 1  - BLOCKSIZE = 512 (8 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.53  GB / s
N = 4096 - ILP = 2  - BLOCKSIZE = 256 (8 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.61  GB / s
N = 4096 - ILP = 4  - BLOCKSIZE = 128 (8 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.74  GB / s
N = 4096 - ILP = 8  - BLOCKSIZE =  64 (8 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.74  GB / s
N = 4096 - ILP = 16 - BLOCKSIZE =  32 (8 blocks - each block processes 512 elements)  - Bandwidth = 0.56  GB / s

N = 8192 - ILP = 1  - BLOCKSIZE = 512 (16 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 1.4  GB / s
N = 8192 - ILP = 2  - BLOCKSIZE = 256 (16 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 1.1  GB / s
N = 8192 - ILP = 4  - BLOCKSIZE = 128 (16 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 1.5  GB / s
N = 8192 - ILP = 8  - BLOCKSIZE =  64 (16 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 1.4  GB / s
N = 8192 - ILP = 16 - BLOCKSIZE =  32 (16 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 1.3  GB / s

...

N = 16777216 - ILP = 1  - BLOCKSIZE = 512 (32768 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 12.9  GB / s
N = 16777216 - ILP = 2  - BLOCKSIZE = 256 (32768 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 12.8  GB / s
N = 16777216 - ILP = 4  - BLOCKSIZE = 128 (32768 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 12.8  GB / s
N = 16777216 - ILP = 8  - BLOCKSIZE =  64 (32768 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 12.7  GB / s
N = 16777216 - ILP = 16 - BLOCKSIZE =  32 (32768 blocks - each block processes 512 elements) - Bandwidth = 12.6  GB / s
```